# Using gsub in list of dataframes with R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name1=c("nd:f","nd:i","nd:c","nd:g","b:rd"),name2=c("21-12-2001","name","-",15,"-"))
df2 <- data.frame(name1=c("nd:i","nd:c","nd:g","nd:y","a:nd"),name2=c("11-01-2001","name",3,"-","-"))
lt <- list(df1,df2)
```

How can I remove `"-"` sign for a given fixed interval in the list for the colum `name2`?:

```
df1$name2[2:3] # for elements 2:3 use gsub("-","",x)
```

And store the corrected (gsub) values back into the `lt` list.

Comment: Why do you want to specify the position?

Comment: Because the values before contain for example dates; like 31-2-2011 and that removes "-" so I want to keep that intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like the following:

```
lapply(rapply(lt, function(x) 
  gsub("^-$", "", x), how = "list"), 
  as.data.frame)
# [[1]]
#   name1      name2
# 1  nd:f 21-12-2001
# 2  nd:i       name
# 3  nd:c           
# 4  nd:g         15
# 5  b:rd           
# 
# [[2]]
#   name1      name2
# 1  nd:i 11-01-2001
# 2  nd:c       name
# 3  nd:g          3
# 4  nd:y           
# 5  a:nd
```

It seems like although `rapply` can handle keeping the data as a `list`, the `data.frame` attribute is lost (hence the extra `lapply(..., as.data.frame)`.

By using `"^_$"` as our pattern in `gsub`, we're saying to look for exactly that pattern. Dates won't be affected.

---

Perhaps a better option, though, is to convert those `"-"`s into `NA`. For this, you can try [my `makemeNA` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/makemeNA.R) from [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

To use this approach you would simply do:

```
library(SOfun)
lapply(lt, makemeNA, "-")
# [[1]]
#   name1      name2
# 1  nd:f 21-12-2001
# 2  nd:i       name
# 3  nd:c       <NA>
# 4  nd:g         15
# 5  b:rd       <NA>
# 
# [[2]]
#   name1      name2
# 1  nd:i 11-01-2001
# 2  nd:c       name
# 3  nd:g          3
# 4  nd:y       <NA>
# 5  a:nd       <NA>
```

Comment: great, and since I have you on the line, how would I include also "," (remove comma) only found between numbers: like 12,1 ... 0,1232 etc. is it possible to include into that existing gsub? thanks

Comment: @Max, What would be the desired result? "12,1" -> "121"? or "12 1"?

Comment: @Max, sure. Just try changing the pattern to something like `"^-$|,"`.

Comment: This is what I thought initially too just inserting conditional sign | but I remembered from one occasion I have tried that id didn't work. Thanks