# R - rapply function across one column of multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, apply, lapply, gsub

I have a list of multiple dataframes. Each dataframe contains the same columns.  I'd like to make changes on a particular column over all dataframes in the list.
I can't seem to figure out how to call a single column, however.

```
df1 <- data.frame("col1"=c("foo-1", "foo-1", "bar-7"), "col2" = c("blu-e", "gre-en", "blue"))
df2 <- data.frame("col1"=c("bar", "bar", "foo-2", "foo"), "col2" = c("green", "orang-e", "yell-ow", "pink"))
dflist <- list(df1, df2)


>df1
col1    col2
foo-1   blu-e
foo-1   gre-en
bar-7   blue

>df2
col1    col2
bar     green
bar     orang-e
foo-2   yell-ow
foo     pink
```

I'd like to replace the `-` in both `df1` and `df2`, but only in `col2`.

Example:

```
>df1
col1    col2
foo-1   blue
foo-1   green
bar-7   blue

>df2
col1    col2
bar     green
bar     orange
foo-2   yellow
foo     pink
```

I've tried this code (which I tweaked from two related SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016359/how-to-directly-select-the-same-column-from-all-nested-lists-within-a-list), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153539/using-gsub-in-list-of-dataframes-with-r)):

```
newdf <- rapply(dflist, function(x) gsub(pattern="\\-", "", x, `[[`, "col2"), how="list")
```

but this `gsubs` on BOTH `col1` and `col2`. Example:

```
>df1
col1   col2
foo1   blue
foo1   green
bar7   blue

>df2
col1    col2
bar     green
bar     orange
foo2    yellow
foo     pink
```

How can I reference just a single column? I'm still new to the `apply` family, so if a different function is needed let me also know.

**EDIT:**
**ANSWER provided in comment by @alistaire**

> rapply is complicated, but you don't really need it; just lapply will
>   do: lapply(dflist, function(x){x$col2 <- gsub('-', '', x$col2); x}) –
>   alistaire Feb 24 at 4:35

Comment: `rapply` is complicated, but you don't really need it; just `lapply` will do: `lapply(dflist, function(x){x$col2 <- gsub('-', '', x$col2); x})`

Comment: This is great! Would this also work for a list of lists of dataframes? something like x[[]]$col2.

Comment: Depending on structure you may need to `lapply` `lapply`, but generally yes, it's possible.

Comment: do you have a particular reason for keeping these data.frames separate? why not rbind (or, more efficient, data.tables rbindlist) them together and just apply one function (vectorised -> more efficient) to the result?

Comment: where did this list come from? why dont you apply the transformation during that process instead of afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Use lapply instead:

```
lapply(dflist, transform, col2 = gsub("-", "", col2))
```