# R add columns based on modifying other columns of dataframes within a list

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I would like to add a new column D to data.frames in a list that contains the first part of column B. But I'm not sure how to adress within lists down to the column level?

create some data

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = "hey", B = "wass.7", C = "up")
df2 <- data.frame(A = "how", B = "are.1", C = "you")
dfList <- list(df1,df2)
```

desired output:

```
# a new column removing the last part of column B

[[1]]
    A      B  C D
1 hey wass.7 up wass

[[2]]
    A     B   C D
1 how are.1 you are
```

for each data frame I did this, which worked

```
df1$D<-sub('\\..*', '', df1$B)
```

in a function I tried this, which is probably 
    not correctly addressing the columns and returns 
    "unexpected symbol..."

```
dfList <- lapply(rapply(dfList, function(x) 
x$D<-sub('\\..*', '', x$B) how = "list"),
  as.data.frame)
```

the `lapply(rapply)` part is copied from [Using gsub in list of dataframes with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153539/using-gsub-in-list-of-dataframes-with-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out

```
lapply(dfList, function(x){
   x$D <-sub('\\..*', '', x$B);
   x
 })
[[1]]
    A      B  C    D
1 hey wass.7 up wass

[[2]]
    A     B   C   D
1 how are.1 you are
```

Comment: My answer would have `'\\..*$'` as a pattern.

Comment: that works fine, thanks a lot. If I don't use the additional `x` after the semicolon, I'm only getting column D, could you explain why that is? I can't find the "bind D to x" part in the function...

Comment: @crazysantaclaus the "bind D to x" part is `x$<- ... ` (just exactly as in your code) and you should use the `x` after `;`so that R prints the complete resulting dataframe you have created inside the list call.

Comment: hm but if I do e.g. `dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) 
x$D<-sub('\\..*', '', x$B))` I have only `[[1]]
[1] "wass"

[[2]]
[1] "are"`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: what would the $ sign change?

Comment: For a complete explanation about `$`, please execute `?"$"` in you R console or follow this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)

Comment: @crazysantaclaus In this case, nothing. But in general it means "end of string", so the pattern would get everything from the first period until the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The `rapply` solution does work. However, you needed a comma before the *how* argument to resolve the error. Additionally, you will NOT be able to assign one new column only replace existing ones. Since `rapply` is a recursive call, it will run the `gsub` across every element in nested list so across ALL columns of ALL dataframes.

Otherwise use a simple `lapply` per [@JilberUrbina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49177250/1422451).

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = "hey", B = "wass.7", C = "up", stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(A = "how", B = "are.1", C = "you", stringsAsFactors = F)
dfList <- list(df1,df2)

dfList <- lapply(rapply(dfList, function(x) 
  sub('\\..*', '', x), how = "list"),
  as.data.frame)

dfList

# [[1]]
#     A    B  C
# 1 hey wass up

# [[2]]
#     A   B   C
# 1 how are you
```

Comment: ah interesting, I would go with Jilber's answer, though, as I would like to keep the original column